# VB.NET Remainder Function

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to do is make a line of text appear every 50 strings read. I was trying to find a reaminder function to use on the `GlobalVariables.TransferTracker` interger, but I couldn't find anything online. Is there such a funciton? Or a differen't/better way to do this? If it helps here is my code:

```
       Do While TransferRecord.Read()

            'Start of writing to the SQL server.
            SQLServerConnection.Open()

            'SQL statement to transfer all the data that fits the requirements to the SQL server.
            Dim SQLCommand1 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.b_Pulp_PI_Forte (" & _
                                              "mill, " & _
                                              "keyprinter_datetime, " & _
                                              "bale_line_num, " & _
                                              "pulp_line_id, " & _
                                              "bale_id, " & _
                                              "drop_datetime, " & _
                                              "layboy_position, " & _
                                              "bale_gross_weight, " & _
                                              "gross_value_flag, " & _
                                              "bale_airdry_pct, " & _
                                              "airdry_value_flag, " & _
                                              "sheets_per_bale, " & _
                                              "grader_test_flag, " & _
                                              "dropped_num, " & _
                                              "created_by, " & _
                                              "CreatedDateTime, " & _
                                              "Who_did_it, " & _
                                              "Last_change_datetime) " & _
                                              "VALUES (" & _
                                              "'850', " & _
                                              "'" & ProdDate & "', " & _
                                              "'" & BaleLineNum & "', " & _
                                              "'" & BaleLine & "', " & _
                                              "'" & BaleNumber & "', " & _
                                              "'" & ProdDate & "', " & _
                                              "'0', " & _
                                              "'" & GrossWeight & "', " & _
                                              "'" & GrossWeightFlag & "', " & _
                                              "'" & AirDry & "', " & _
                                              "'" & AirDryFlag & "', " & _
                                              "'0', " & _
                                              "'N', " & _
                                              "'0', " & _
                                              "'BaleTrac', " & _
                                              "'" & Date.Now & "', " & _
                                              "'BaleTrac', " & _
                                              "'" & Date.Now & "')")

            'If DisplayCode is checked this will be printed to the screen.
            If ApplicationPropertiesWindow.DisplayCodechkbx.Checked = True Then
                MainTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & SQLCommand1.CommandText)
                GlobalVariables.DisplayCode = True
            End If

            'Executing the SQL statement.
            SQLCommand1.Connection = SQLServerConnection
            SQLCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLServerConnection.Close()
            GlobalVariables.TransferTracker = GlobalVariables.TransferTracker + 1

            'This is where I would like to have the remainder function.
            'Making message to show that program is still running.
            If GlobalVariables.TransferTracker = 50 Then
                MainTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "50 records transferred.")
            End If
        Loop
```

Right now I just have it set up so it will fire at 50 records, because I couldn't find the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The remainder is an operator in VB, `Mod`:

```
If GlobalVariables.TransferTracker Mod 50 = 0 Then …
```

As a general advice, don’t write `… = True` in your conditions. Its redundancy is redundant.

Comment: Okay, I think that should work. Thank you, it makes it much easier now haha. And yeah I know, this program is very old and from when I first started, I am just touching up the faults in it.